# Why is graphical editing of Hebrew at Mi Yodeya intolerable?

Tags: bug, design, rtl

When I write in Hebrew on [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) (the Stack Exchange site about Judaism) and add punctuation or a point at the end of a sentence, the punctuation will move to the start. For example: "Yesterday I went to the pool." This will become "אתמול הלכתי לבריכה." although it's written in Hebrew from right to left. Can you fix it?

Comment: It is a general problem on the web with Hebrew. I am surprised this is the first time you have experienced it. The BIDI (Bi-Directional) text algorithms are not all that great. Things are much better than they were say 15 years ago, but mixing languages (and directions) is still a problem everywhere.

Comment: @Oded This isn't specific to Hebrew is it? I imagine it would be the same for all RTL languages.

Comment: @Mysticial - absolutely. Arabic, Farsi and other RTL languages have the same issue. If one is aware of it, manually fixing by adding [RLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) and [LRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) where appropriate can help.

Comment: You can not solve it on this site? I surf a lot of sites where this Hebrew Edit excellent. (This is not the first time I met it but you can always fix it (this site for Jewish:))

Comment: @Oded according to Jon's answer on the dupe, Mi Yodeya should have RTL support, so is this indeed a bug?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - it doesn't, not "complete" support. It has a virtual keyboard with a button to insert an `&rlm;` - that isn't the same as say - detecting an all/mostly Hebrew (or other RTL language) and making the whole post with a `dir="rtl"`, for instance (not saying that's the right thing to do - just giving an example).

Comment: @Eliyahu-Shmuel - it isn't simple, not when the UI and *most* content on the site is not Hebrew. I see tweets on twitter that are impossible to read because of this. I suspect that the sites you mention are primarily for Hebrew content and writing, where English is the exception to the rule.

Comment: But I know that develop software and it does not sound that complicated to create a code that identifies the beginning of the last punctuation mark law and puts it at the end of the trial.

Comment: Usually comments of this nature go from local Meta to MSE, but please see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88/right-to-left-formatting-for-hebrew

Comment: You'd [think so, wouldn't you](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/)?

Comment: "it does not sound that complicated to create a code" Funny, that.

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be on Meta Mi Yodeya?

Comment: @doru no, there are other sites where it is plausible for someone to post something containing Hebrew text (Linguistics.SE, for example). The equivalent problem also happens for Arabic text on Islam.SE.